# Woocommerce query return products, order by total_sales

Tags: mysql, wordpress, woocommerce

I've checked the woocommerce reports and products that haven't been sold are being fetched in the query?

Here is the query:

```
   SELECT  wp_terms.name as categoryname,v1.meta_value as thevalue, wp_terms.slug as categoryslug, wp_posts.post_title as mytitle, wp_terms.term_id as categoryid,wp_term_taxonomy.parent as categoryparent FROM wp_posts
    INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id)
    INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy ON (wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = wp_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id)
    INNER JOIN wp_terms ON (wp_term_taxonomy.term_id = wp_terms.term_id)
    INNER JOIN wp_postmeta v1 ON (wp_posts.ID = v1.post_id) AND v1.meta_key LIKE 'total_sales'
    WHERE wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' AND wp_posts.post_type = 'product' AND wp_terms.slug='garden-lighting' AND wp_posts.post_title NOT LIKE '%cable%' AND v1.meta_value !=0
    ORDER BY v1.meta_value DESC
LIMIT 8
```

I checked the results of the array returned and products that haven't been sold are returning with a total_sales value?

Where did i go wrong?  I want products returned for a specific category and ordered by total sales.

Comment: With the exception of trailing spaces, note that `LIKE 'x'` is the same as `= 'x'`. Now, if I was wanting help with a problem like this, I'd provide proper DDLs and a desired result. Also, when working with an EAV, like wp's term_taxonomy system, I prefer to pivot/'pseudo-normalise' the dataset first. It can be slower but I find it easier to understand.

Comment: I used percentages, so in my query it isn't the same as `='x'`

Comment: For some reason, the percentages haven't materialized in your example above.

Answer (score 2):

Why not use [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) instead of trying to write an SQL statement?

If I've understood you correctly, the following should return the first 8 posts in the 'garden-lighting' category sorted by sales and then by title.

```
$args = array( 
    'query_id' => 'exclude_cable',
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'category_name' => 'garden-lighting',
    'posts_per_page' => 8,
    'orderby'  => array( 'meta_value_num' => 'DESC', 'title' => 'ASC' ),
    'meta_key' => 'total_sales'
);
$new_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

**Edit** I have added a few extra parameters. One I forgot to designate the product post type! Oops. But additionally, I have added a `query_id` parameter. WordPress doesn't do anything with this by default, but we can filter the [`posts_where`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/posts_where) clause and use it there to only modify the `posts_where` for this specific query.

```
add_filter( 'posts_where' , 'so_28478323_posts_where', 10, 2 );

function so_28478323_posts_where( $where, $q ) {
    if ( 'exclude_cable' == $q->get( 'query_id', null ) ) {
        $where .= " AND wp_posts.post_title NOT LIKE '%cable%'";
    }
    return $where;
}
```

Comment: thanks for this but i need to exclude any title with the word `cable` in it?  How can i amend your query to accomplish this?